# Void pointer and casting in function argument

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers, void-pointers

Here is a code snippet.

```
class NetworkRequestChannel {
public:
  ...

  NetworkRequestChannel(const unsigned short _port_number,
    void * (*connection_handler) (int *));
  ...
private:
  ...
}
```

My question is about the argument `void * (*connection_handler) (int *)`. I have a vague idea how to read that, and it's as a void pointer to an object named `connection_handler` that is being then cast to an int pointer. But I know that's almost certainly wrong, and I'm not sure how else to interpret it.

Comment: It's a function pointer, accepting a function that takes a single `int*` as an argument and returns a `void*` value (a generic memory address). The parameter itself is named `connection_handler`.

Comment: Note that `class NetworkRequestChannel` indicates that this is C++, not C.  The answer is the same, but the code shown is not valid C.

Comment: That's something else that I have been confused about for a while. I'll admit, this is for a class, which is why I was trying not to put too many details and just get the one simple answer. However, in all of my professors' assignments, his files are C files with `.C` and `.H` extensions. However, HE uses classes even in his own predefined files, and the makefile we are given uses `g++ -g`. It's like some C/C++ hybrid that he's trying to do that I haven't seen up until this class.

Comment: In my experience, professors aren't really known to use the best practices. :P

Comment: But how does that even compile? How is a `.C` file able to compile with classes, and why use g++ instead of gcc?

Comment: It's just a file extension. There could be anything inside of the file, and the g++ compiler will treat it as c++.

Comment: `.C` (upper case) is sometimes used as a C++ file extension. Only suitable on case-sensitive file systems of course

Comment: If you do not understand a C declaration try using [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The argument

```
void * (*connection_handler) (int *)
```

Is a pointer to a function taking one argument of type `int*` and returning a `void*`

Answer (score 0):

It's the syntax for a function pointer. The parameter in question accepting a function that takes a single `int*` as an argument and returns a `void*` value (a generic memory address).

You can read more about it [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html).

(That's quite an old article, and I encourage people to comment or edit this answer to list ones that emphasize modern C++ practices. Disregard this if the article I linked is actually up to date with the best practices!)